# Reactjs- resetting drop downs when one drop down is changed

Tags: reactjs, office-fabric

Overview:

I have 3 dropdown which are used to filter the data:

```
<MyDropdown label="Filter by name" options={this.array1}
              changeState={this.event1.bind(this)}/>
<MyDropdown label="Filter by name" options={this.array2}
              changeState={this.event2.bind(this)}/>
<MyDropdown label="Filter by name" options={this.array3}
              changeState={this.event3.bind(this)}/>
```

My requirement is to reset the other dropdown to the first index whenever any of the dropdowns is changed by the user.

I can achieve this functionality using JQuery, but is it possible through react without calling the render() on these udate?

> **UPDATE**

Controller for MyDropdown (it uses office fabric dropdown)

```
 <Dropdown
    label={this.props.label}
    onChanged={this.props.changeState}
    options={this.props.options}
    defaultSelectedKey={this.props.options.length > 0 ? this.props.options[0].key : undefined}
 />
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `MyDropdown`? The answer largely depends on whether your components are controlled or uncontrolled.

Comment: @Chris I have updated the post.

Comment: MyDropdown is a custom component?

Comment: it should be done with react only? or you can use normal javascript

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala no.. its Office fabric dropown

Comment: @raviraja is it possible through React?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve **dom** changes without calling **render()** function.

MobX provides api to handle state changes without calling **setState()**

where every variables will be an **observable** that can trigger value changes like in **Angular** with **2wayDataBinding**.

**https://mobx.js.org/intro/overview.html**

You can use the following npm module .

***https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select***

which has all the API one needs, for example in your case,
you need to change the value of options once option is selected.

```
         <Async
            id="state-select"
            onBlurResetsInput={false}
            onSelectResetsInput={false}
            className="team-creation-dropdown-input"
            simpleValue
            clearable={false}
            rtl={false}
            searchable
            disabled={false}
            noResultsText="No results found"
            placeholder="Last Name"
            name="selected-state"
            labelKey="last_name"
            options={this.state.salesExecutives}
            value={teamMemberDetail.id}
            onChange={e => this.addNewTeamMember(e)}
            loadOptions={(input, callback) => { this.getOptions(input, callback, 'salesExecutives'); }}
            onInputChange={searchValue => { this.salesExecutivesSearch(searchValue, 'last_name'); }}
          />
```

By using this you can simple splice the value on  **onInputChange or onChange**.